# Ethereum LES getProofsV2 Always Returns [] (Empty Nodes)

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I'm unable to get an Ethereum LES getProofsV2 (or getProofs) request to produce a ProofsV2 (or Proofs) response with anything but an empty array of Nodes.  This is for a request targeted to a GETH node open to LES connections.

The request arguments are `[B_32 (blockHash), B_32 (key), B_32 (key2), P (fromLevel)]`.  I'm providing a `blockHash` from any recently mined block; a `key` as the Keccak256 hash of a 20-byte account (with transactions from months ago), a `key2` as 32-bytes of 0, and `fromLevel` as 0.  I'm expecting to get back an array of `Nodes` with the last node having the RLP encoding of the `AccountState` (with `{nonce,balance,...}`.  Is that expectation correct?  Or would I only expect to get an array of Nodes if `key` had transactions in the specified `blockHash`? [Fact is, I tried both - `blockHash` w/ or w/o transactions, still nodes is `[]`].

Specifically, this is the request data:

```
ETH: LES-ProofsV2-Req:   L  1: [
ETH: LES-ProofsV2-Req:     L  4: [
ETH: LES-ProofsV2-Req:       I 32: 0x0a89dd55d38929468c1303b92ab43ca57269ac864175fc6208ae739ffcc17c9b
ETH: LES-ProofsV2-Req:       I 32: 0x272cf200ca06815ab2170fde0901e7da10ab1dddc31223184f139def3b09f670
ETH: LES-ProofsV2-Req:       I 32: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
ETH: LES-ProofsV2-Req:       I  0: 0x
ETH: LES-ProofsV2-Req:     ]
ETH: LES-ProofsV2-Req:   ]
```

Where the blockHash `0x0a89...` is blockNumber `5732521` and key2 is the hash of account `0x49f4C50d9BcC7AfdbCF77e0d6e364C29D5a660DF`.

For completeness, the response is:

```
ETH: LES-PROOFSV2: L  3: [
ETH: LES-PROOFSV2:   I  0: 0x
ETH: LES-PROOFSV2:   I  4: 0x11d1a228
ETH: LES-PROOFSV2:   L  0: []
ETH: LES-PROOFSV2: ]
```

What is needed to make a successful GetProofsV2 request?

Comment: If you have any trouble getting responses here, you might also try https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/ (Sorry I don't have more help than that to offer)